# Bluetooth speaker disconnects after about 10 mins

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have an Altec Lansing Life Jacket 2 Bluetooth speaker and an LG headset. I can pair both to my MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 16.04 and can play audio through them, but after about 5-10 mins they disconnect and Ubuntu's Bluetooth setting shows "Off". I have to turn off the devices,restart them, and then turn on Bluetooth in Settings and reconnect them again (they are still paired, though). But the same thing happens again after a few minutes. Any one have similar issues and were you able to resolve them?